# LIKE query returns empty row in php code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db of 3 tables. I am trying to access store names of selected button which works with the query:

```
SELECT sm.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) as Category_Names,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_id) as Category_ID 
FROM `store_manufacture` sm , Categories c, Store_Category sc 
where sm.sm_id = sc.store_id 
  AND c.cat_id = sc.cat_id 
  AND sm.sm_brand_name LIKE "H%" 
GROUP BY sm.sm_id
```

**Output**

[image]

But when i apply query for showing selected letter data. It does not diplay the store names.

**PHP**

```
$selected_val='';
if(isset($_POST['getValue'])){
    $selected_val = $_POST['getValue'];
    $sql='SELECT sm.*,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) as Category_Names,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_id) as Category_ID 
      FROM store_manufacture sm , Categories c, Store_Category sc 
      where sm.sm_id = sc.store_id 
        AND c.cat_id = sc.cat_id 
        AND sm.sm_brand_name LIKE"'.$selected_val .'% 
      GROUP BY sm.sm_id"';

    $sm=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sm,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $sm_id = $row['sm_id'];
        $name = $row['sm_brand_name'];
        $cat_ids = $row2['Category_ID'];
  ?>
 <a href="store_profile.php?name=<?php echo $name ?>&cat_id=<?php echo $cat_ids ?>"
  class="list-group-item"><?php echo $name ?></a>
  </div>
<?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Or at least test `if ( ! $sm ) { // I have an error in my query }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select is wrong.

```
$sql="SELECT sm.*,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) as Category_Names,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_id) as Category_ID 
      FROM store_manufacture sm , Categories c, Store_Category sc 
      where sm.sm_id = sc.store_id 
        AND c.cat_id = sc.cat_id 
        AND sm.sm_brand_name LIKE '{$selected_val}%' 
      GROUP BY sm.sm_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed a double quote after your wildcard

```
AND sm.sm_brand_name LIKE"'.$selected_val .'%"   <--
```

Answer (score 1):

You misplaced one double quest in your query

```
<?php
$sql='SELECT sm.*,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) as Category_Names,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_id) as Category_ID 
      FROM store_manufacture sm , Categories c, Store_Category sc 
      where sm.sm_id = sc.store_id 
        AND c.cat_id = sc.cat_id 
        AND sm.sm_brand_name LIKE"'.$selected_val .'%" 
      GROUP BY sm.sm_id';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $sql='SELECT sm.*,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) as Category_Names,
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_id) as Category_ID 
      FROM store_manufacture sm , Categories c, Store_Category sc 
      where sm.sm_id = sc.store_id 
        AND c.cat_id = sc.cat_id 
        AND sm.sm_brand_name LIKE"'.$selected_val .'%" 
      GROUP BY sm.sm_id';
```

remove " after group by and add after like operator %